# Solr: How to search for a full match on a text field? Is there a hidden equal() operator?

Tags: full-text-search, solr, equals, match, operator-keyword

it is too simple to describe:

q=mydynamicfield_txt:"video"

I want only hits when mydynamicfield is **exact** "video.
Other way round, how to supress hits, where "video" is only part of the field (like "home video").

Is this supported with Solr3.1 out of the box, or do I have to add my own **special brackets** like "SOLRSTARTSOLR video SOLRENDSOLR" in my  index, to retrieve later my term between "START" and "END". Kind of manual regex anchoring.

This is PITA cause it needs special handling in index/gui and breaks highlighting.

Where is the way to go?

regards

Peter
(=PA=)

Comment: do you know this page? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: Hmm.. is this a quiz? Sorry, but I cannot find a hint under all the indexing relevant stuff on the page you mentioned. Another hint? thx (=PA=)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to create untokenized(KeywordAnalyzed) field and search within it - all your text will be distinct token in Solr index.
Other solution is to write filter which will read token count from index and compare to query tokens i.e. filter entities where doc_tokens > query_tokens assuming that all query tokens are matched.

Comment: Untokenized fields work but the problem with untokenized fields is that they don't work with things like stemming.